# Are there alternatives to AddPicture? (C#, Epplus)

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using EPPlus to convert a .csv file to .xlsx and converting one of the columns to a barcode image using ZXing. Everything works but the performance of AddPicture is causing an issue. The .csv file can have thousands of records, and the larger the record count the slower the application runs. I've narrowed the issue down to the AddPicture function and read that it copies the image to the temp folder, inserts it into the spreadsheet, and deletes the temp image, which is alot of disk I/O. If I comment out the AddPicture function the application runs in 1-2 seconds. Enabling the AddPicture function increases runtime exponentially (based on the number of records) to the point of being unusable.

```
for (var r = 2; r < (workSheet.Dimension.End.Row + 1); r++)
{
    //set row height
    workSheet.Row(r).Height = 50;

    //create barcode string
    string myBarcode = String.Format("{0}", workSheet.Cells[r, 7].Text);

    //create image
    string newFileName = "C:/DUMP/barcodes/" + myBarcode + ".jpeg";

    if (!File.Exists(newFileName))
    {
        createBarcode(myBarcode, 100, 40);
    }

    //add image to worksheet
    var picture = workSheet.Drawings.AddPicture(myBarcode, new FileInfo (newFileName));

    //set image position
    int eppRow = r - 1;
    picture.SetPosition(eppRow, 10, 7, 5);

    //enable "TwoCell" to maintain column anchors
    picture.EditAs = OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.eEditAs.TwoCell;
}
```

I first attempted to create the image in memory and insert directly into the spreadsheet. The version shown above is writing the image to disk and only creating a new image if necessary. Neither version performs well when handling a large number of records.

EPPlus does a great job of converting the .csv file, and ZXing can quickly create the images. Those work flawlessly. But using AddPicture to insert the image into the Excel file is causing performance issues. Does anyone have other suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: I am having this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, I have a solution, that is, I can calculate the size of each picture ,then calculate the row height according to the picture size, and adjust the height of the entire workbook according to their row height calculated from above info.  finally add the picture,

in short ,set  the desired rows height before you add any picture.

I hope it will be useful to you

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30805842)